# Facebook: fake and real account deletion

Tags: facebook

Can Facebook delete one's real account if it finds out they also have a fake one?

For example, John Doe has two profiles: John Doe and Jane Smith. Facebook discovers Jane Smith is fake. Can account John Doe be deleted as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is typical with free services, any account can be deleted if Facebook decide they want to delete it.

An explanation is found in Facebook [Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php), section 4:

> 1. You will not provide any false personal information on Facebook, or create an account for anyone other than yourself without permission.
> 2. You will not create more than one personal account.

and section 14:

> If you violate the letter or spirit of this Statement, or otherwise create risk or possible legal exposure for us, we can stop providing all or part of Facebook to you.

So, creating a fake account is a violation of Terms of Service, and a person violating the Terms of Service may be denied any access to Facebook.

The part "or otherwise create risk for us" is a way of Facebook reserving the right to block access in other cases not covered by ToS.

Answer (score 0):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/975828035803295?helpref=uf_permalink):

> Facebook is a community where people use their authentic identities. It's against the [Facebook Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards) to maintain more than one personal account.
>
> Keep in mind that a personal profile is for non-commercial use and represents an individual person.
>
> If we discover that you have multiple personal profiles, we may ask you to close the additional profiles. We also remove any profiles that impersonate other people.

Creating multiple accounts comes under violation of Community Standards, so they can remove any account or both accounts and restrict you joining the Facebook.